# How to assign to Rails ActiveRecord conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Hey I wasn't quite sure what to call this but here's the deal.

I'm trying to only assign things to my database value if

1. There isn't a value in the database already, and
2. The value I'm assigning isn't blank.

The rudimentary version of this code is:

```
venue.address = venue_json['address'] if venue.address.blank? && !venue_json['address'].blank?
```

where `venue` is my ActiveRecord result.

This is what I have now (a little better). With the `init_value` in the Venue.rb class.

```
 Venue.init_value(venue.address, venue_json['address'])

 def self.init_value(record, value)
   if record.blank? && !value.blank?
     record = value
   end
 end
```

I'd like to get to this point, but really have no idea how.

```
venue.address.init_value(venue_json['address'])
```

especially since I'd like it it work with any attribute of the ActiveRecord class not just the `address` value.

Answer (score 0):

Separating it into a method sounds like a good idea, but in this case it makes more sense to use an instance method rather than a class method.

```
def init_attribute(attribute, value)
  self.update(attribute => value) if self.send(attribute).blank? && value.present?
end

venue.init_attribute(:address, venue_json['address'])
```

Some quick comments on the snippet above:

- Using direct assignment won't persist the database value. You could go with something else like [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) or [`update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column). Or you can use assignment and then call [`#save`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Validations/save) on the object.
- Whenever you need something not to be blank, you can use the more readable [`Object#present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) which is part of ActiveSupport.
- You'll need to call the method with the same name as the attribute on the database object. For this you'll want to use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) from Ruby.

Comment: So this definitely works.  And is better than what I had but it doesn't quite reach what I was going for as I'd like the call to look like `venue.address.init_attribute(venue_json['address'])`.  It's mostly a matter of style, but I was hoping there was some cool reflection-y type stuff that could make that work.  Great advice though.  Thanks!